# CFA chi-square value ordinal variables

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

For my thesis I need to know how the chi-square value is computed with a CFA for ordinal variables, using DWLS (preferably in R). I know that for continuous variables the chi-square is computed in the following way: $\chi^2= (N-1) \times F_{ML}$, but I can't find how to compute it for ordinal variables.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Leslie. Do you know much about maximum likelihood estimation, in general?

Comment: Thanks, I thought it worked in the following way: It minimizes the following formula (where S is the covariance matrix of my sample and $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix implied by $\theta$: $F(S,\hat{\Sigma})= tr(S\hat{\Sigma}) + (ln(|\Sigma|) - ln|S|)$. And by minimizing that, it maximizes the likelihood that the difference between S and $\hat{\Sigma}$ comes from sample fluctuations. However is it correct that the first part of the function ($tr(S\hat{\Sigma}$) is a real number and de second part ($(ln(|\Sigma|) - ln|S|)$) a matrix? Moreover I do not get the difference between

Comment: maximum likelihood and log likelihood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the same way for ordinal variables as it does for continuous: you evaluate the sample covariance/correlation matrix with no structure (alternative model), with the structure you specified (null model), and take the difference of the two likelihoods. If the software you use calculates $F_{ML}$, then you can calculate the $\chi^2$ using the formula you gave. If it calculates log likelihoods, you can compute twice the difference in log-likelihoods.

The use of $F_{ML}$ is a historic artifact of what Karl Joreskog wrote about forty years ago. It is unfortunate that it is still stuck in the SEM world: for one thing, $F_{ML}$ really depends on the sample size, while $\chi^2$ is pivotal (i.e., has a specific asymptotic distribution).

There are several R packages for structural equation modeling, including `sem`, `lavaan` and `OpenMx`. You may want to specify which one you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I forgot to mention that I'm using lavaan. Furthermore I thought that FML is biased when using ordinal variables? And what do you mean with FML really depends on sample size? Because my sample is quite big (2981 subjects). My RMSEA (<0.4) and CFI values (>0.97) are all good but I have a big chi-square value, so my professor told me that mathematically speaking my model was not correct.